# How to say, "I made/wrote this based off _____"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

To clarify, using "based off" in a way that's citing inspiration for a creation (vs. backing something up with a fact). I found にもとづいて, but I'm not sure if it's the most natural choice for the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

にもとづいて is the most direct translation of "based on". But providing more context on what you want to say might help, because it may sound too formal.